# Não está sobrepondo o valor

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

Estou querendo que a informação final do calculo sobrescreva o que já está salvo na tabela de Estoque, como seria para efetuar isso, pois o Save, está sobrescrevendo de modo certo, tentei aplica no update, porém não salva.

Update:

```
var ConsultaAntigo = ckm.Compra(viewModel.Id);
var Antigo = ConsultaAntigo.OrderBy(c => c.NomeProduto).FirstOrDefault();
var Consulta = ckm.ControleEstoque(viewModel.ProdutoId);
var estoque = Consulta.OrderBy(t => t.NomeProduto).FirstOrDefault();    
int AntigoFinal = estoque.Quantidade - Antigo.Quant;    
int quantidadefinal = AntigoFinal + viewModel.Quant;    
estoque.Quantidade = quantidadefinal;
```

DAO Compra:

```
public void Update(Compra compra)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.AbreSession())
    {
        ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
        session.Update(compra);
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: você está executando o `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: No DAO, está executando Update

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta como funciona o DAO, @LeandroAngelo